# VMware virtual machine 12 change hostname

Tags: vmware-workstation, opensuse, sles

Is there a setting from the VMware virtual machine version 12 to change the name of the machine(hostname) ,I am booting Linux Suse 12.3

Answer (score 1):

Login to the machine, and change the hostname.